# My formula is in DNF, will z3 convert it into CNF?

Tags: z3, smt

DNF SAT is polynomial time, while CNF SAT is NP-Complete. If I have a first-order formula whose Boolean skeleton is already in DNF, will z3 be aware of that, or it will blindly convert the formula to CNF to solve by CDCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may, especially in an interactive context with push/pulls and/or the tactics used in the API. When that happens, the resulting constraints should be relatively easy to solve though. This does however beg the question why all the cubes are handed to Z3, when each of the them could be checked independently, leaving less room the heuristics to get confused.

Comment: Thank you. That means iteratively checking each cups one by one is more efficient than checking the disjunction of all the cups. Am I correct?

Comment: Probably, yes. It really depends on what exactly is in each of the literals. For example, when all the disjuncts share a theory expression that the simplifier can simplify and that makes all the disjuncts false, it would be quicker to run Z3 on all the disjuncts at the same time to avoid repeated calls to the simplifier. Conversely, if each of the discjuncts fully describes a different model, then it would be unnecessary overhead to encode them all just to pick the first one as the result.